# Are the triangle's side lengths valid?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to write a program where the user can input three side lengths of a triangle as real numbers and the program will answer if it is valid or not. The problem I am running into is this:

The results I get are wrong. For example. I enter 22.2, 22.3, 22.4 and it will print "Yes".

I enter 55, 55, 100 and it prints "Yes" again, instead of printing no like it should.

I type 4, 6, 1 and it prints "no" correctly. I cant figure out why its giving me the correct answer only sometimes. Thank you!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//prototype for my function which will take 3 real number variables
bool valid_triangle(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void)
{
    //prompts user to input 3 real number variables using get_float from cs50 library
    float a = get_float("Enter first side of triangle: ");
    printf("\n");
    float b = get_float("Enter second side of triangle: ");
    printf("\n");
    float c = get_float("Enter third side of triangle: ");

    //calls function valid_triangle. If true prints yes, if false prints no.
    bool valid = valid_triangle (a , b, c);
    if (valid == true)
    {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no\n");
    }
}

bool valid_triangle(float a, float b, float c)
{
    if //if the sum of any 2 sides are less than the third, it is not a triangle
    ((a + b < c) || (a + c < b) || (b + c < a))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: FYI `if (valid == true)` is not needed as `if (valid)` would suffice

Comment: 55,55,100 **is** a triangle. Your code is correct. You're not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code is correct and there is no problem. The OP is mistaken about the validity of the results.

Comment: Please explain ***exactly*** why you think `55` `55` `100` is not valid.  It sure seems valid to me. Its called an [Isosceles Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle)

Answer (score 1):

An invalid triangle has one side which is more than the sum of the two other sides. But if you want to check for a valid triangle, make sure *all* sides are less or equal to the other sides.

```
bool valid_triangle(float a, float b, float c)
{
    return a<=b+c && b<=a+c && c<=a+b;
}
```

In you see that a `55,55,100` triangle is valid

```
bool valid_triangle(a=55, b=55, c=100)
{
    return 55<=55+100 && 55<=100+55 && 100<=55+55;
    // return true
}
```

[image: fig1]

and for a `45,45,100` triangle ([which is impossible](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=triangle+with+sides+45+45+100))

```
bool valid_triangle(a=45, b=45, c=100)
{
    return 45<=45+100 && 45<=100+45 && 100<=45+45;
    // return false 
}
```

the routine identifies it as not valid because `100 > 45+45 = 90`

Comment: Actually, if two sides sum to the same as the third side, that **wouldn't** be a triangle since all three points would be colinear.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I am happy to hear my code is correct. It really helped me understand when you wrote out the variables in the function like that. I will have to do more research on triangles.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - it is technically still feasible to create a triangle with no height, but that is up to the _op_ to use equality or not in the check.